# Is it possible to make a div to grow with textarea like Jquery Elastic plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my comment box I used Jquery Elastic plugin for auto height of textarea and this textarea placed into a main relative `div` with also another `div` which rendered preview of the comment.

Textarea and preview have there own Z-index to show one above one.

Now, If I write something on textarea and press enter key to line break, It will grow below but I want my main div also grow with textarea without overflow.

Is it possible to make a div to grow with textarea.

Here is my working example:

```js
var smileys = {
':)': '<img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png" border="0" alt="" />',
':-)': '<img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png" border="0" alt="" />',
':D': '<img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
  $('textarea').elastic();
});

function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
```

```css
#main {
position:relative;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 450px;
}
.chat {
  width: 100%;
}
.preview {
  width: 100%;
  font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:14px;
  color:#000000;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; z-index:997;
}
.chat > textarea {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:14px;
    border:0px none;
 min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute; color:transparent;
  top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div class="chat">
      <div class="preview">
      </div>
          <textarea name="comment" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="comment" placeholder="Problem occurs here after 6th line. . ."></textarea>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust main div css height dynamic by jquery:

```
$('#main').on('keyup',function() {
  $(this).css('height','auto');
  $(this).css('height',Math.max(this.scrollHeight)+'px');
});
```